# Parsing HTML link from around 600 URLs using Perl

Tags: html, perl, url

I have the list of around 600 drugs as a input and I have written a perl script to get the list of 600 URLs for all these drugs, grabs the URL content. Also, there is a link inside each URL termed Shared/Embed Graph that can be clicked to view the HTML source code. However, I need to make the script such that it clicks all these links inside all the 600 URLs and prints the 600 HTML source codes to STDOUT in perl. Right now my script is:

```
<c>
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use LWP::Simple qw(get);
#use HTML::Parse;
use YAML;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;
use Template::Extract;

my $infile = $ARGV[0];
my $outfile =  $ARGV[1];
open (IFILE, "<", $infile) || die "Could not open $infile\n";
open (OFILE, ">", $outfile) || die "Could not open $outfile\n";

my @arrayofdrugterms;

while (<IFILE>) {
  chomp;
  push (@arrayofdrugterms, $_);
}
#print "@arrayofdrugterms\n";
my $url;
foreach my $arrayofdrugterms( @arrayofdrugterms) {
  $url = "http://www.drugcite.com/?q=$arrayofdrugterms\n";
  print OFILE "$url\n";
}
close OFILE;
#open outfile for reading
open (OFILE, "<", $outfile) || die "Cannot open $outfile\n";
my @arrayofurls;
my $mech;
my $ext;
my @result;
my @link;
my $template;
my $content;
while (<OFILE>) {
  chomp;
  @arrayofurls = split ( ' ', $_);
  #print "@arrayofurls\n";
  foreach my $arrayofurls ( @arrayofurls) {
    #print "$arrayofurls\n";
    $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 0);
    $mech->get( "$arrayofurls" );
    #print $mech->get( "$arrayofurls" ). "\n";

    $ext = Template::Extract->new;
    #print "$ext\n";

</c>   



<b>
$template = "<div id="[% DrugCite %]" style="[% padding:10px %]">
<img src="[% http://www.drugcite.com/img/?    item=vg&q=$arrayofdrugterms&meddra=pt style=border;0px; alt=Top 10 $arrayofdrugterms ADVERSE EVENTS - DrugCite.com %]">
<br />
<a href="[% http://www.drugcite.com/?q=$arrayofdrugterms   style=font-size:7pt;margin-left:20px;color:#c0c0c0;text-decoration:none %]">"[% Source DrugCite %]"
</a>
</div>";
</b> 

<c>          

    @result = $ext->extract($template, $mech->content);
    print "@result\n";

    #print Dumper "\@result" . "\n";

    foreach ($mech->links) {
      if( $_->[0] =~ /^Share\/Embed Graph$/) {
        $mech->get($_->[0]);
      }
=cut
      #else {
        #print "Not found the required link\n";
      #}
      #else {
        #push (@link, $_->[0]) . "\n";
      #} 
=cut               
    }#end foreach
    #print STDOUT "$mech->content\n";
    #print Dumper \@link . "\n";
    foreach (@result) {
      #print YAML::Dump $_;
    }
  }
}
</c>
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks

Comment: We need to see at least the HTML soruce code around the graph.

Comment: <div id="DrugCite" style="padding:10px;"><img src="http://www.drugcite.com/img/?item=vg&q=ASPIRIN&meddra=pt" style="border:0px;" alt="TOP 10 ASPIRIN ADVERSE EVENTS - DrugCite.com"><br /><a href="http://www.drugcite.com/?q=ASPIRIN" style="font-size:7pt;margin-left:20px;color:#c0c0c0;text-decoration:none;">Source DrugCite</a></div>